# i18n camespace in SAP Commerce / Spartacus

Tags: internationalization, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I dont get how namespaces work in SAP Commerce. (https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/1.x/i18n/)

How i think it works is as follows:

- Add the HTML

  {{ 'updatePasswordForm.oldPassword.placeholder' | cxTranslate }}
- add that in your translation.ts

  updatePasswordForm:{
  oldPassword:{
  placeholder: "Old password"
  }
  },
- Config of chunks and namespaces mapping

with the last part i have my problem. I don't know where to put it and my project just uses the default one. How do do i find that?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using translation chunks as described there:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/#configuring-chunks-and-namespace-mapping

Working solution.
In app.module.ts in providers provide this config:

```
provideConfig({
    i18n: {
        backend: {
            loadPath: 'assets/i18n-assets/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        },
        chunks: {
            'forms': ['updatePasswordForm'],
        },
    },

}),
```

Afterwards, we can create a json file in src/assets/i18n-assets/en/forms.json and inside this file add the following lines:

```
{
    "updatePasswordForm": {
        "oldPassword": {
            "placeholder": "Old password"
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation

loadPath defines the place where the translation chunks will be located.

{{lng}} defines a folder for translations language, e.g., en, de etc.

{{ns}} is placeholder for chunks.
In chunks we defined 'forms' field which corresponds to our translations file - forms.json.

Also, we have to map translations to namespaces - we have defined that our forms.json file contains namespaces ['updatePasswordForm'], so when translations will be needed for namespaces that starts with updatePasswordForm, the forms.json file will be loaded.

Comment: I found out that one easy way to get the name of your chunk is to just add a typo. In my case i wrote:
{{ 'updatePasswordForm.oldPassword.placeholderr' | cxTranslate }} 
(added a 2nd r in placeholderr)
and my frondend showed me:
[myAccount:updatePasswordForm.oldPassword.placehodler]
So i knew that myAccount is my cunk.